# How to solve empty space problem between frozen part and scrollable part of resizable primeng table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, primeng

I need a p-table which has frozen columns and scrollable columns. All the columns are also resizable and table is in expand mode. When one of the frozen columns is resized left, there appears empty space between frozen columns and scrollable columns. I want no empty space between frozen part and scrollable part when the column is resized. Is there any way to do that?

Table before column width is resized:

[image: Table before column is resized]

Table after Year column is resized by dragging left border of Year:
[image: Table after Year column is resized by dragging left border of Year]

There is empty space between Year column and Brand column. How can I solve this problem? And I must use column resize mode 'expand', not 'fit' mode, because that is the user requirement.

Here is the code snippet for the above table:

```js
scrollableCols = [
  { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
  { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
];

frozenCols = [
  { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin' },
  { field: 'year', header: 'Year' }
];

cars = [
  { 'vin': 1, 'year': 2011, 'brand': 'Toyota', 'color': 'black' },
  { 'vin': 2, 'year': 2012, 'brand': 'Toyota', 'color': 'black' },
  { 'vin': 3, 'year': 2013, 'brand': 'Toyota', 'color': 'black' },
  { 'vin': 4, 'year': 2014, 'brand': 'Toyota', 'color': 'black' },
  { 'vin': 5, 'year': 2015, 'brand': 'Toyota', 'color': 'black' },
  { 'vin': 6, 'year': 2016, 'brand': 'Toyota', 'color': 'black' },
  { 'vin': 7, 'year': 2017, 'brand': 'Toyota', 'color': 'black' }
];
```

```html
<p-table [columns]="scrollableCols" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols"  [value]="cars" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="200px"    frozenWidth="400px" [resizableColumns]="true"  columnResizeMode="expand">
  <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
    <colgroup>
      <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width:200px">
    </colgroup>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pResizableColumn>
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns" class="ui-resizable-column">
        {{rowData[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: could you add some of your code? it's hard to tell where or how to fix this without knowing what you did

Comment: sorry I forgot to add code.

Comment: what happens if you remove the size from your colgroup? or use a percentage value instead of px?

Comment: If I use style="width:25%" instead of style="width:200px", the problem remains same.

Comment: and i guess if you remove the style completely it's not looking like you want?

Comment: yes, and I tried that and the problem remains same.

Comment: could you maybe create a minimal working example? eg via codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-utonl 
This is the codesandbox link. Please have a look.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @MichaelK. No, not yet. And I had to convert the table to ag-grid. So I didn't give much time to this.